# I am new to SQL, and trying to learn what I can through books and websites

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I would like to write a MySql expression which:

- displays each status and number of occurrences of each status using the Count(*) function
- display the result of the Count(*) function as CountStatus
- groups by status and display the results in descending order of CountStatus

This is what I already have:

```
SELECT
    Status, COUNT(*) AS 'num'
FROM 
    COUNT(*)
```

Comment: ...FROM tableName GROUP BY status

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or the question you're asking. No one cares that you're new to SQL and trying to learn, and that title will be of absolutely no use to someone when it turns up in a search result in the future. Your title should provide information relevant to your question, not information on your personal experiences.

Comment: You're selecting the count from *what*, exactly? If you need a SQL introduction, I'd highly recommend picking up the basics through a course or reference book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select Status, COUNT(Status)  from ***Count()***
-- please be sure to use the right name of the table after From. 
group by Status
order by COUNT(Status) desc

:)

Comment: Thanks Manaswi B, your response put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to the question.

SELECT
Status, COUNT(*) 'CountStatus'
FROM STUDENT
   GROUP BY Status
   GROUP BY CountStatus DESC;